# How do I resolve MarkMembersAsStatic FxCop error?

Tags: windows, winforms, code-analysis, fxcop

I have a method ResetMethod(ClassA a) in a class and I have accessed this method by property of ResetMethod's class like this:

```
public class MyClass1
{
   public MyClass1()
   {
   }

   public void ResetMethod(ClassA a)
   {

   }
 }

 public class MyClass2
 {
    MyClass1 class1;

    public MyClass2()
    {
         ClassA a= new ClassA();
         MyClass1.ResetMethod(a);
    }

    public MyClass1 MyClass1 
    {
       get
       {
          if (myClass1 == null)
             myClass1 = new MyClass1 ();
          return myClass1 ;
       }
       set
       {
          myClass1 = value;
       }
    }
 }
```

While running FxCop rules, for method ResetMethod, it shows this error:

> The 'this' parameter (or 'Me' in Visual Basic) of 'MyClass1.ResetMethod(MyClassA)' is never used. Mark the member as static (or Shared in Visual Basic) or use 'this'/'Me' in the method body or at least one property accessor, if appropriate.

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: If you are in fact using the method then you have a false positive that can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You invocation of `MyClass1.ResetMethod(a);` is already calling a static method. So the code you posted does not compile to my understanding.

So all that's left to the do is to make the method itself static:

```
   public static void ResetMethod(ClassA a)
   {
       // ...
   }
```